# c# mapping and value to another value in a list in Unity

Tags: c#, list, loops, unity-game-engine, search

I'm trying to make a visualisation where I have to do a lot of searches through arraylists. I have a Unity slider with float values that represent time.

I also have 2 arraylist, of sizes up to 300k each, one with Time values, and the other one with ID number for each object.

The thing I have to do is to map the sliders changes with the arraylist of time then get the right object ID to perform something like color changing.

What I currently do is that I made a function that look for the right time value each time the slider changes value which is stupid.

I seriously do not know what I should do or what I can use. I'm currently using linq .select and where function which loops through the list each time the slider changes value but I want it to be of complexity ordo(1)

For example, 
1.Slider changes value, 
2. I use the slider value to get the right object ID

my Code Snippet:

```
void Update()
{       
    if(isPlaying){
        fps = 1/Time.deltaTime;
        timeSlider.value += (1000/fps) *speed;
    }
}

//example of spikeTimes, it is way bigger!
spikeTimes=[1.2, 5.9, 9.6];
public void SliderFunction(float currentTime){
    var tempSpikes = spikeTimes
        .Select((x,i) => Mathf.Round(x)==Mathf.Round(currentTime) ? i : -1)
        .Where(i => i != -1)
        .ToList();
    ChangeColor(tempSpikes);
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code of what you're already trying to do so we can help better?

Comment: If all slider values are unique then use a Dictionary and hold the object id as the value to the slider key

Comment: Are the time values unique? Then you could use an `IDictionary` with the time as key which provides much faster lookups than an `IList`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! I included some code snippets, hope it helps.

I will look into dictionary!

Comment: This is what Dictionary is used for. Use  Dictionary instead of List